# Can Marker interface be replaced with Seralizable

Tags: java, interface, serializable

Looking at below code, `Marker interfaces` signals that my `BusinessObject` is `Serializable`(right?).

Old code:

```
public final class State implements BusinessObject 
   ...
 }
public class Location implements BusinessObject{
   ...
 }

import java.io.Serializable;
public interface BusinessObject extends Serializable{   
}
```

My question is, since the sole purpose of `BusinessObject` is to indicate that it is `Serializable`, can this be simply replaced by:

```
public final class State implements Serializable {
...
public class Location implements Serializable {
...
```

and delete `BusinessObject.java`?

Comment: It depends on whether you also want to use that marker interface for other things.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, as long as `BusinessObject` really only extends `Serializable`.

Now, in a broader context, you may want to perform sanity checks before getting rid of it.

For instance, open the type hierarchy of your `BusinessObject` interface in your IDE and look at all implementing classes, extending interfaces, etc.

There may even be edge cases where the code base would compile but issues would happen at runtime if the `BusinessObject` interface was referenced through reflection, or in declarative markup such as JSP.

For those cases, I would also recommend a textual search for `BusinessObject` throughout your whole project.

That may also help you root out deprecated comments.